# How can I make the client accessing my site make another request and use its response's data in the initial request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, axios

User-->Initial Request-->(User-->2nd Request)-->2nd Response for 1st Response

I have tried using axios to make the 2nd request but that is happening server side instead of use rside.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Also why do you need to initial request/response if it's the second request/response that gives you the data?